# Python package not found even though the package is there

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-codegen

I downloaded the python package "swagger-client" in order to interface with a website's API (swagger is a framework to automate API creation for client/server communication). Then, I installed the swagger-client package using:

```
./venv/bin/python python-client/setup.py install
```

I can see that the package is deployed in

> venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/swagger_client-1.0.0-py3.7.egg

Also, my IDE PyCharm shows that the swagger-client package is "found":
[image]
[image]

However, when I try to import the package using "import swagger_client", I get an error `<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'swagger_client'"), <traceback object at 0x7fd74cac4948>)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the runtime environment the same that the package is installed?

Comment: Yes, the runtime environment is the same "virtual-env" configured in pycharm. The other packages shown on the picture can also be imported correctly. I wonder if maybe it is due to the fact that "swagger_client" is a .egg file?

Comment: Also I installed all the other packages using PyCharm UI, swagger_client is the only one which I installed manually with setup.py, so maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the method I used to install the `swagger_client` module was wrong.

I used:

```
./venv/bin/python3.7 python-client/setup.py install
```

which produced this warning:

```
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
```

but this is the correct way to do it:

```
cd python-client
../venv/bin/python3.7 setup.py install
```